# Consola del navegador web no muestra warnings - REACT

Tags: reactjs, consola, warnings, eslint

Se supone que la consola debería mostrar este tipo de advertencias, por ejemplo: cuando defino un estado y no se utiliza debería aparecer un Warning que me indique que el estado no se esta utilizando, pero no lo muestra. Sí aparece en el vs code pero no en el navegador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso es porque el warning es por parte del Server Side Rendering no del Client Side por eso te aparece en la terminal de VSC, Si tuvieras un error de renderizado del lado del cliente aparecería en la consola del navegador

Answer (score 0):

Puede estar sucediendo que no veo que tu aplicación este iniciada en modo estricto.
Este modo habilita a por ejemplo advertencias como las que estas señalando.
[image: Código]

Documentación:
https://es.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

Comment: el modo estricto está en el index.js